# generate all possible combinations of n bit binary numbers wherein k bits are always set using backtracking only

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinations, backtracking

Getting stuck on how to set the bits while backtracking. Unable to exclude 001,010 and 100 in the output. providing an algorithm would be greatly helpful.

`Eg:n=3,k=2,arr={0,0,0},index=0`

```
void printwithKbitset(int n,int k,int arr[],int index)
{
   if(k==0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            cout<<arr[i];
        cout<<"\n";
   return; 
   }
    if(n>1)
        printwithKbitset(n-1,k,arr,index+1);
   if(k>0)
   {
   arr[index]=1;
   printwithKbitset(n,k-1,arr,index);
 arr[index]=0;  
    }

Output:   
001
011
010
101
110
100
```

---

Comment: "providing an algorithm would be greatly helpful." yes it would, but an algorithm for what? What is the objective?

Comment: It's for practice

Comment: @user4581301 objective acheived without help,no thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is using `std::next_permutation`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    for (auto e : v) {
        std::cout << e << " ";   
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {0, 1, 1};

    do {
        print(v);
    } while (std::next_permutation(std::begin(v), std::end(v)));
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/CLYNO0)

Comment: Can it be implemented without using STL? Also the code doesn't seem to be making use of backtracking

Comment: You can look at implementation of `std::next_permutation` if you want to know how it is implement. It can be rewritten.